# Not getting Messages effects on iOS 10.2 (14C92)

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I sent my wife a message from an iPhone 7 to her iPhone 6S. Both are running iOS 10.2 (14C92), but when she received my message, she got:

> (sent with celebration)
>
> (sent with love)

... instead of getting the cool effects I thought I was sending her. She can see the new emoji that come with the update, but not the new effects.

Comment: Did it ever work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a non reproduceable issue as shown in the OP's answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what happened, but eventually it just started working. Perhaps there's a glitch in the release.